# Unable to resolve module. File doesn't exist. The point is that yesterday it worked while today it shows this error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAiTw.png)

We use react-native gifted-chat. Interesting fact is that yesterday it worked perfectly while when today we run a simulator it is showing this strange error. We tried the solution recommended in the simulator and did those 3 steps while it still shows the same error. How can it be solved? Here is the code:

```
import React, {Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import {GiftedChat, Actions, Bubble, SystemMessage} from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
import CustomActions from '../components/CustomActions';
import CustomView from '../components/CustomView';

export default class MessagesScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      messages: [],
      loadEarlier: true,
      typingText: null,
      isLoadingEarlier: false,
    };

    this._isMounted = false;
    this.onSend = this.onSend.bind(this);
    this.onReceive = this.onReceive.bind(this);
    this.renderCustomActions = this.renderCustomActions.bind(this);
    this.renderBubble = this.renderBubble.bind(this);
    this.renderSystemMessage = this.renderSystemMessage.bind(this);
    this.renderFooter = this.renderFooter.bind(this);
    this.onLoadEarlier = this.onLoadEarlier.bind(this);

    this._isAlright = null;
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        messages: require('./data/messages.js'),
      };
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  onLoadEarlier() {
    this.setState((previousState) => {
      return {
        isLoadingEarlier: true,
      };
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this._isMounted === true) {
        this.setState((previousState) => {
          return {
            messages: GiftedChat.prepend(previousState.messages, require('./data/old_messages.js')),
            loadEarlier: false,
            isLoadingEarlier: false,
          };
        });
      }
    }, 1000); // simulating network
  }

  onSend(messages = []) {
    this.setState((previousState) => {
      return {
        messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, messages),
      };
    });

    // for demo purpose
    this.answerDemo(messages);
  }

  answerDemo(messages) {
    if (messages.length > 0) {
      if ((messages[0].image || messages[0].location) || !this._isAlright) {
        this.setState((previousState) => {
          return {
            typingText: 'React Native is typing'
          };
        });
      }
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this._isMounted === true) {
        if (messages.length > 0) {
          if (messages[0].image) {
            this.onReceive('Nice picture!');
          } else if (messages[0].location) {
            this.onReceive('My favorite place');
          } else {
            if (!this._isAlright) {
              this._isAlright = true;
              this.onReceive('Alright');
            }
          }
        }
      }

      this.setState((previousState) => {
        return {
          typingText: null,
        };
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  onReceive(text) {
    this.setState((previousState) => {
      return {
        messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, {
          _id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000),
          text: text,
          createdAt: new Date(),
          user: {
            _id: 2,
            name: 'React Native',
            // avatar: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png',
          },
        }),
      };
    });
  }

  renderCustomActions(props) {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      return (
        <CustomActions
          {...props}
        />
      );
    }
    const options = {
      'Action 1': (props) => {
        alert('option 1');
      },
      'Action 2': (props) => {
        alert('option 2');
      },
      'Cancel': () => {},
    };
    return (
      <Actions
        {...props}
        options={options}
      />
    );
  }

  renderBubble(props) {
    return (
      <Bubble
        {...props}
        wrapperStyle={{
          left: {
            backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  renderSystemMessage(props) {
    return (
      <SystemMessage
        {...props}
        containerStyle={{
          marginBottom: 15,
        }}
        textStyle={{
          fontSize: 14,
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  renderCustomView(props) {
    return (
      <CustomView
        {...props}
      />
    );
  }

  renderFooter(props) {
    if (this.state.typingText) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.footerText}>
            {this.state.typingText}
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GiftedChat
        messages={this.state.messages}
        onSend={this.onSend}
        loadEarlier={this.state.loadEarlier}
        onLoadEarlier={this.onLoadEarlier}
        isLoadingEarlier={this.state.isLoadingEarlier}

        user={{
          _id: 1, // sent messages should have same user._id
        }}

        renderActions={this.renderCustomActions}
        renderBubble={this.renderBubble}
        renderSystemMessage={this.renderSystemMessage}
        renderCustomView={this.renderCustomView}
        renderFooter={this.renderFooter}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  footerContainer: {
    marginTop: 5,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  footerText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#aaa',
  },
});
```

**app.js navigator part**

```
const Main = StackNavigator(
  {
    Post: {screen: PostScreen},
    Signin: {screen: SigninScreen},
    Signup: {screen: SignupScreen},
    Forgetpass: {screen: ForgetpassScreen},
    Drawer: {screen: Drawer},
    Welcome: {screen: WelcomeScreen},
   Messages: {screen: MessagesScreen},
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Signin",
    headerMode: "none",
  },
);
```

Also MessagesScreen was imported in the app.js and implemented inside the react-navigation. As I said it worked yesterday perfectly. While now causes error.

Comment: Can you add the project structure and the part where you add the `MessagesScreen` to your navigation please.

Comment: Sure. I've added some part of app.js where it was used. Also it imported before the usage.  You can check in the above. It worked perfectly yesterday. And nothing was changed until now.

Comment: Have u tried the solutions given in the error message like deleting node_modules and installing them all back freshly etc?

Comment: Yes I did all 3 steps and  still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that yesterday you installed the module without saving and today you did a fresh `npm install` so you no longer have it. Can you verify that 1) `react-native-gifted-chat` is listed as a dependency in `package.json` and 2) `react-native-gifted-chat` exists under `node_modules` directory?